# Excel CSV cell format for MYSQL tinyint

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm having issues importing a CSV file to my MYSQL Table.  Mainly the tinyint fields I use for 1 or 0 data (indicating days of the week).

The tinyint fields always show NULL, I've used formats: number with no decimal, blank, general.

Any ideas as to which format will work?

Comment: MySQL version? sample data? table schema? import SQL statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, it was a column heading issue, didn't like capital letters.